# OpenCV for python. Error: no module named cv2

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, importerror

Hello stackoverflow community  :) 
I need some help. I've written a simple program from the python website and when I run the program, it says :

ImportError: No module named cv2

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#read image into matrix.
m =  cv2.imread("python.png")

#get image properties.
w,h,bpp = np.shape(m)

#print image properties.
print "width: " + str(w)
print "height: " + str(h)
print "bpp: " + str(bpp)
```

I already tried to install openCV but it seems that I didn't install properly, this is the tutorial I followed to install it. When I tried to installed the dependencies it said:

http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

```
E:Package 'libtbb-dev' has no installation candidate
E: unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

I ignored that package and procced to the next step (download the openCV 2.4.9).

When I tried to generated the Makefile using cmake I got the next warnings

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by  "Qt5Core" with any of the following names:
    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

    Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
    Call Stack (most recent call first)
    CMakeLists.txt:466 (include)
```

The same happens with the next packages:

- Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
- qt5gui-config.cmake
- Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
- qt5widgets-config.cmake
- Qt5TestConfig.cmake
- qt5test-config.cmake
- Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
- qt5concurrent-config.cmake

and at the end this Error shows up:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR
  QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY
  QT_QTTEST_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTTEST_LIBRARY QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:34 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:466 (include)
```

I've searched all the file system but couldn't find the above files. I also read that If anything goes wrong, I have to go back, correct the errors by maybe installing extra packages and then run cmake again. BUT, how do I install those extra packages?

I ran the next commands and all the libraries are installed and updated to the newest version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get updgrade
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Can someone please help me get a usable install of OpenCV as simply as possible. I would really appreciate it. I'm stuck in this project.

PS. I also couldn't find a cv2.so file I searched everywhere... I used the next command:

```
sudo find/name "cv2*"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/&ved=0ahUKEwjin97Xo-HUAhVPJ1AKHU9XByMQFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNF_I4Ge4ZJ068mkBmNBsMJK2ndV3w) and try installing from scratch.

Comment: I also recommend the link @RickM. shared, as I used it for installing and worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mark this question as solved, My problem was that my university does not allow us(Students) to download from risky pages(they call them fake websites). Either way, my only solutions were:

1. Get a Raspberry Pi 3 (Wi-fi Integrated, since I was using the Pi 2 and I needed to connected via Ethernet) and ask a friend if he could shared me his private network.
2. Go to another university to try if I can downloaded them there.

I took the first option, now I got the Pi 3 for free, my university gave it to me. =)

Answer (score 0):

Install CV from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Go to **OpenCV, a real time computer vision library.**

Choose right version based on your bit version, python version

```
sudo pip install <whl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Python bindings were not built. Try:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpython3.5-dev python3-numpy
```

If it still shows the error, then you might want to head [here](http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/).

Comment: I tried the link you sent me doing a step by step,  and it seems that openCV was installing properly, but I faced another problem "I ran out of space in my SD card". I 'm using NOOBS and I'm not able to use all the space of my memory. I'll install the RASPBIAN image on SD card and I let you know what happened ASAP, thanks mate.

Comment: @AndresMitre happy to help. No need to thank me. Accepting the answer would do it :). Let me knoow if you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

After `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` I had to import module with `import sys` and append the packages directory with `sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')` in my .py code.

Now everything (about opencv)is working fine.